# Duplication error when entering data into Firebase Android Studio

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am having a problem when I am adding data to Firebase, instead of adding the new data into the database, it is taking the data already in there and repeating itself and then adding the new data.

For example if I have titles "Red Dead" and "GTA" and I want to add "COD". Instead of the database looking like "Red Dead" "GTA" and "COD" it is looking like "Red Dead" "GTA" "Red Dead" "GTA" and then "COD".

Any ideas on how to fix this please ??

```
package com.example.gearoidodonovan.books

import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.renderscript.Sampler
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.firebase.database.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.add_note.view.*
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

var mRef:DatabaseReference? = null
var mNoteList:ArrayList<Note>?= null





override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    mRef = database.getReference("Notes")
    mNoteList = ArrayList()



    add_new_note.setOnClickListener {

        showDialogAddNote()


    }
}

override fun onStart(){
    super.onStart()
    mRef?.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
        override fun onCancelled(pO: DatabaseError) {
        }

        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            for (n in p0!!.children) {
                var note = n.getValue(Note::class.java)
                mNoteList?.add(note!!)

            }

            val noteAdapter = NoteAdapter(applicationContext, mNoteList!!)
            note_list_view.adapter = noteAdapter

        }

    })

}


fun showDialogAddNote() {
    val alertBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)

    val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.add_note, null)

    alertBuilder.setView(view)

    val alertDialog = alertBuilder.create()
    alertDialog.show()


    view.btnSaveNote.setOnClickListener {
        val title = view.etTitle.text.toString()
        val note = view.etNote.text.toString()

        if (title.isNotEmpty() && note.isNotEmpty()) {
            var id = mRef!!.push().key!! //reference 1

            var myNote = Note(id, title, note, getCurrentDate())
            mRef!!.child(id).setValue(myNote)
            alertDialog.dismiss()


        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }


    }

}

    fun getCurrentDate(): String{
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        val mdformat = SimpleDateFormat("EEEE hh:mm a ")
        val strDate = mdformat.format(calendar.time)
        return strDate


}
}
```

Here is my notes class

```
package com.example.gearoidodonovan.books


import com.google.firebase.database.Exclude
import com.google.firebase.database.ServerValue



class Note {
var id:String?= null
var title:String? = null
var note:String?= null
var timestamp: String? = null

constructor(){

}

constructor(id: String, title: String, note: String, timestamp: String){
    this.id = id
    this.title = title
    this.note = note
    this.timestamp = timestamp
}







}
```

And here is my adapter class

```
package com.example.gearoidodonovan.books

import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.note_layout.view.*
import kotlin.collections.ArrayList

class NoteAdapter(context: Context, noteList: ArrayList<Note>)
: ArrayAdapter<Note>(context, 0, noteList) {


override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
   val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.note_layout,parent ,false)

    val note:Note = getItem(position)
    view.titleText.text = note.title
    view.timeText.text = note.timestamp.toString()
    return view


}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `childEventListener` instead of `valueEventListener`.

Answer (score 0):

If it happens when you want to list data from Firebase, initialize your `ArrayList` before adding new data. Because `onDataChange` method take all data from Firebase and displays within the ListView.

So you must initialize between `onDataChange` and `for`